# Changing recurring values in the table

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a function which calculates some values and assigns it to a 1-dimension array. I need to have non-repeated values in it. So if a value is repeated I must redo the calculation before passing it to the array. Can someone help me with this?

For example:

```
array(0) = function(x,y) 
arrat(1) = function(a,b) 
arrat(2) = function(s,t)
...
array(0) = 1 
array(1) = 2 
array(2) = 2, this function[function(s,t)] must be recalculated
```

I tried code like this:

```
for i = lbound(arr1) to ubound(arr1) - 1
    for j = i + 1 to ubound(arr1)
        if arr1(i) = arr1(j) then 
             'array(i) =?
            j=j-1
        end if
    next j
next i
```

but each value array need another function.

Comment: can you show your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can incorporate another function which checks first if the value is already present.

```
Function Dupe(oneDarr, myitem) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Lbound(oneDarr) To Ubound(oneDarr)
        If oneDarr(i) = myitem Then Dupe = True: Exit For
    Next
End Function
```

Then in your main sub, do something like this.

```
Dim x
Do
    x =  function(s, t)
    If Not Dupe(array, x) Then Exit Do
Loop
array(2) = x
```

Don't know your specifics, so just giving you something to start with.
Hope this helps.